# Scipy not supported error. Cant load json file

Tags: python, json, compiler-errors, pycharm, loading

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
import numpy as np
import tflearn as tf
import tensorflow
import random
import json

stemmer = LancasterStemmer


# Reading the json file
with open('intents.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/collinrausch/Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Instructions for updating:

non-resource variables are not supported in the long term

Scipy not supported!
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 File "/Users/collinrausch/Project/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did pip install Scippy.